# Open folder on left and right side of the window

Tags: vba

I'm using the following code to open a folder in min szie

```
Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & "D:\Archive\", vbMinimizedFocus)
Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & "D:\Shortcuts\", vbMinimizedFocus)
```

I would however love to to let pop up next to each other. One on the left size and one on the right. Like this

[image]

Anybody know whether there is a way to move screens after opening?

Comment: I can do it with two instances of notepad but never tried it with windows explorer. The Windows Explorer has evolved with each version of windows. The newer explorer do not have Titles See this [OLD](http://www.daleisphere.com/wp-content/uploads/windows-xp-windows-explorer-folders-view.jpg) and [New](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Windows_Explorer_Vista.png) In case you have XP, it is easier to use API like Findwindow. Still let me play with it and check

Comment: BTW which OS are you using? From the screenshot it looks like you are using XP?

Answer (score 4):

**Tried And Tested** [Win 7 / Excel 2010 - VBA / 1920 X 1080 (Mobile PC Display)]

Here is a very basic example on how to achieve what you want. We will be using four API's for this.

1. [FindWindow](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/FindWindow.shtml)
2. [SetParent](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/SetParent.shtml)
3. [SetWindowPos](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/SetWindowPos.shtml)
4. [GetDesktopWindow](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/GetDesktopWindow.shtml)

I will not individually cover these APIs. To understand what do they do, simply click on the respective links.

**LOGIC:**

The newer explorer do not have Titles as I mentioned in my comments above. For example see this

[image]

However playing with Spy++, I was able to see that they had captions but were not displayed on the folder's title bar. See screenshot below.

[image]

1. Use `FindWindow` API to locate the window using it's `Caption`
2. Using `SetParent`, we are assigning the parent window i.e Desktop for the specified child window (Folder Window).
3. Reposition the window using `SetWindowPos` API

**CODE:**

Paste this code in a module and change the folder as applicable. This is a very basic code and I am not doing any error handling. I am sure you will take care of it.

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias _
"FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" _
(ByVal hWndChild As Long, ByVal hWndNewParent As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32.dll" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, _
ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As Long

Private Const SWP_NOZORDER As Long = &H4
Private Const SWP_SHOWWINDOW As Long = &H40

Private Sub Sample()
    Dim lHwnd As Long
    Dim Fldr1Path As String, Fldr2Path As String
    Dim winName As String
    Dim Flder1X As Long, Flder1Y As Long
    Dim FlderWidth As Long, FlderHeight As Long

    '~~> Folder one X,Y screen position
    Flder1_X = 50: Flder1_Y = 50
    '~~> Folder Width and Height. Keepping the same for both
    FlderWidth = 200: FlderHeight = 200

    '~~> Two Folders you want to open
    Fldr1Path = "C:\Temp1"
    Fldr2Path = "C:\Temp2"

    '~~> The Top most folder name which is also the caption of the window
    winName = GetFolderName(Fldr1Path)

    '~~~> Launch the folder
    Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & Fldr1Path, vbMinimizedFocus

    '~~> wait for 2 seconds
    Wait 2

    '~~> Find the Window. 
    '~~> I am using `vbNullString` to make it compatible with XP
    lHwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, winName)

    '~~> Set the parent as desktop
    SetParent lHwnd, GetDesktopWindow()

    '~~> Move the Window
    SetWindowPos lHwnd, 0, Flder1_X, Flder1_Y, FlderWidth, _
    FlderHeight, SWP_NOZORDER Or SWP_SHOWWINDOW

    '~~> Similary for Folder 2
    winName = GetFolderName(Fldr2Path)
    Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & Fldr2Path, vbMinimizedFocus
    Wait 2
    lHwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, winName)
    SetParent lHwnd, 0
    SetWindowPos lHwnd, 0, Flder1_X + FlderWidth + 10, Flder1_Y, _
    FlderWidth, FlderHeight, SWP_NOZORDER Or SWP_SHOWWINDOW

    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub

Function GetFolderName(sPath As String)
    Dim MyAr

    MyAr = Split(sPath, "\")

    GetFolderName = MyAr(UBound(MyAr))
End Function
```

**SCREENSHOT:**(*Folders arranged*)

[image]

**EDIT**

**Tried And Tested** [Win XP / Excel 2003 - VBA / on VM]

*Special Thanks to [Peter Albert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1867581/peter-albert) for testing this for me.*

[image]

Comment: Siddharth, thanks a lot for this thorough reply. It works :). I however would like to understand it a little better. Do you have a source for some good tutorials....? What languahe is this by the way?

Comment: Visual Basic. To understand how the APIs work, check the links mentioned in the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with the same 2 folders, you may can easily do this.

1- Open the two folders manually and then set the desired size and location. Close the folder.

2- Then next time you call the script, do the following

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "Explorer /n, D:\Archive\", 4, False 
oShell.Run "Explorer /n, D:\Shortcuts\", 4, False
```

This will open the folder with last saved position and size.

**NOTE** Just tested it on my Win7 machine and it doesnt work. Turns out that Win 7 doesnt remember folder position any more (it only remembers the size). Read more about it [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5b524d53-df97-405d-835f-f081d106a19b/can-we-get-a-straight-answer-windows-does-not-remember-window-size-and-position-bug-or-by?forum=w7itproui).